# Последовательное выполнение задач в gulp 4

Tags: gulp

Как сделать настройку gulp 4, что бы задача 'minify-css-names'(плагин gulp-minify-cssnames) выполнилась корректно.

Имеется 2 файла стилей (генерируются из LESS):

- main.css
- html_styles.css

Нужно, что бы классы и id ужимались корректно, то есть, что бы плагин смотрел сразу в 2 CSS файла и во все PHP файлы разумеется

Текущая настройка gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),

    // Styles
    less = require('gulp-less'),
    lessAutoprefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    uncss = require('gulp-uncss'),
    minifyCssNames = require('gulp-minify-cssnames'),

    // JS
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglyfly = require('gulp-uglyfly'),

    // Image
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),

    // System
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    del = require('del'),
    gulpIf = require('gulp-if')

;



/* Gulp Watcher */
gulp.task('watch', function() {

    gulp.watch('./app/static/styles/**/*.less', gulp.series(['less']));
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.php', gulp.series(['code-files', 'code-files']));
    gulp.watch('./app/static/js/**/*.js', gulp.series(['js']));
    gulp.watch('./app/static/imgs/**/*.*', gulp.series('image-min'));

});


/* Remove 'dist' folder */ 
gulp.task('delete', () => {

    return del([
        'dist/**/*', 
        '!dist/imgs', 
        '!dist/imgs/**/*'
    ]);

});


/* LESS -> CSS */
gulp.task('less', () => {

    return gulp.src('./app/static/styles/*.less')
        .pipe(less({
            plugins: [new lessAutoprefix({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] })]
        }))
        // .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/styles'));

});


/* Minify CSS names */
gulp.task('minify-css-names', () => {

    gulp.src([
            './dist/static/styles/*.css',
        ])
        .pipe(minifyCssNames({
            prefix: '-pre-',
            postfix: '',
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/styles'));

    gulp.src([
            './dist/static/js/scripts.min.js',
        ])
        .pipe(minifyCssNames({
            prefix: '-pre-',
            postfix: '',
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/js'));

    return gulp.src([
            './app/**/*.php',
        ])
        .pipe(minifyCssNames({
            postfix: '',
            prefix: '-pre-'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));

});


/* Optimize JS */
gulp.task('js', function() {

    gulp.src('./app/static/js/html_js.min.js')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/js'));

    return gulp.src('./app/static/js/scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('scripts.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglyfly())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/js'));

});


/* UnCSS */
gulp.task('uncss', () => {

    return gulp.src([
            './dist/static/styles/*.css',
            '!./dist/static/styles/html_styles.css'
        ])
        .pipe(uncss({
            html: ['./app/**/*.php']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/styles'));

});


/* Optimize images */
gulp.task('image-min', () => {

    return gulp.src('./app/static/imgs/**/*.+(png|jpg|jpeg|ico|gif|svg)')
        .pipe(cache(imagemin([

            imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
            imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}),
            imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 5}),
            imagemin.svgo({
                plugins: [
                    {removeViewBox: true},
                    {cleanupIDs: false}
                ]
            })

        ])))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/imgs'));

});


/* Move Code Files */
gulp.task('fonts', function() {

    return gulp.src('./app/static/fonts/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static/fonts'));

});


/* Move fonts */
gulp.task('code-files', function() {

    return gulp.src('./app/**/*.php')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));

});


/* Run Gulp */
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('delete', 'fonts', 'code-files', 'image-min', 'less', 'js', 'minify-css-names', 'watch'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается неверно написал код для задачи 'minify-css-names'. Верный вариант

```
gulp.task('minify-css-names', () => {

    return gulp.src([
            './dist/**/*.+(php|js|css)',
        ])
        .pipe(minifyCssNames({
            prefix: 'pre-',
            postfix: '',
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));

});
```